# Where's the xorg.conf.d in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, xorg

What's the path of the xorg.conf.d directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Answer (score 4):

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Just tried it on my machine and it's definitely there

EDIT: Beaten to the post!